# Writing a fast function to check elements in a matrix

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance, sorting

I'm trying to write a function that checks the elements in a matrix and returns another matrix of the results in booleans.

The input:

`X`: The list of 2D age array as described above.

The output:

The function should return a 2D array with the entries of either 0 or 1 as described above.

The function must run 15 times faster than this one:

```
def check_elems(X):
    out = [[0]*len(X[0]) for _ in range(len(X))]
    for i in range(len(X)):
        for j in range(len(X[i])):
            check = X[i][j]
            if check>=14 and check%5==4 and check!=19:
                out[i][j] = 1
    return out
```

Here's the particular example:

- The person is at least 14
- The person's age ends in 4 or 9
- And the person is not 19

For example, an age array of

```
[[22, 13, 31, 13],
 [17, 14, 24, 22]]
```

will have the output array:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Have you tried out numpy?

Comment: What is the question you are asking here?

Comment: What python is it?

Answer (score 1):

Without numpy:

```
X = [[22, 13, 31, 13],
     [17, 14, 24, 22]]

%timeit check_elems(X)
%timeit [[1 if i%5==4 and i>=14 and i!=19 else 0 for i in l] for l in X]
```

With a standard laptop:

> 2.16 µs ± 15 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
>
> 911 ns ± 2.23 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

**EDIT**

As kindly noted by @user3386109 the previous code does NOT satisfy the *15 times faster* constraint required by OP, that I somehow misread as 1.5 times. I leave my code just as a baseline.

Comment: That's twice as fast, which is good. But not nearly the improvement the question asked for.

Comment: Hi, I want to test my code as well, how exactly did you ran this timeit?